# Visual studio doesn't let me select project for startup

Tags: visual-studio, project, program-entry-point

I have a solution structure like this:
[image]

Normally, I would like to debug 'SoundStudio.MainWindow' but it does not let me start that project:
[image]

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to right-click on SoundStudio project, then select "Set as Startup Project"; in this way you should be able to launch your program and debug it.

Currently it seems you have set WaveFileLib project as startup project (please note the bold white text for its name); from the name I guess it is a library and an error message like "A project with an Output Type of Class Library cannot be started directly" should be prompted out when trying to debug it directly.